# PyCharm "Frames are not Available"... How to add frames so I can view Variables in Debug?

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

Sorry if this is pretty basic, but I can't seem to figure out how to enable/add Frames under the PyCharm Debugger so I can view Variable information, even after selecting a checkpoint. When I'm under the Debugger all I see is "Frame is not available"... I have searched for hours and tried enabling the "Python Exception Breakpoint" checkbox, but that didn't help either. Am I missing something basic? I believe I should have a "main thread" or something like that under the Frames section, but at this point I don't know what else to try... Attached is what I see when I'm under the Debugger. Thank you for any suggestions! :)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just run the code :)

If you'd like to debug a program, there are some ways to do it:

1. `Right-Click` on the tab with file name (`LASClipCPU_test.py` in your case) and select `Debug 'LASClipCPU_test'`

or

2. Go to `Run` and select `Debug 'LASClipCPU_test'`

or

3. Just push the button with the green bug as an icon. It's above file name tab on your screenshot.

More about debugging is [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/debugging.html).

Comment: I tried that, but the problem is that I want to see info about my Variables (e.g., specifics when using a real file in the code). And I can't seem to figure out how to do so with the Frames section not showing anything. Hope this makes sense. Thank you for your time!

Comment: @MartaB. Frames and variables will be available when you start a program. The program is not started on the screenshot above.

Comment: Oh okay. I will try to troubleshoot starting the program in the IDE... thank you!

Comment: This would be normally be considered a low quality question, but it solved my problem, anyway :)